# Java converte caracteres com acento em caracteres "estranhos"

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, codificação-de-caracteres, spring-data

Estou enfrentando um problema um tanto quanto estranho. Tenho um banco de dados MySQL na versão 5.6 e uma tabela com campo do tipo `longblob` que armazena um texto no formato HTML compactado (ZIP). Quando meu site faz uma requisição para o *backend* (utilizo Spring Boot 2.3.3, JPA e Java 11.0.9 Correto da Amazon), o mesmo busca esse registro do banco de dados, descompacta e retorna apenas o texto em HTML para meu site.

Quando faço isso na minha maquina local funciona perfeitamente, mas quando faço isso do servidor, com a mesma versão do Java, o processo não funciona, o *backend* converte os caracteres com acento em caracteres "estranhos".

Esse é um exemplo do texto salvo no banco de dados:

```
<p style="text-indent:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;SAIBAM</span><span style="color:#000000;"> quantos a presente </span><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">Escritura Pública de Cessão e Transferência de Posse</span><span style="color:#000000;"> virem que, sendo aos æData_lav1&gt;, neste Distrito de Itaió, 2º do município e comarca de Itaiópolis, Estado de Santa Catarina, neste Ofício de Notas, sito às margens da Rodovia SC 477, s/n, perante mim, Tabelião de Notas, partes entre si, justas e contratadas a saber</span></p>
```

Esse é o resultado obtido no servidor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ser verificado que todas as letras acentuadas foram convertidas para caracteres "estranhos".

Já tentei alterar a conexão com banco de dados para UTF-8, mas sem sucesso:

```
conexão...&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

Esse é o método que descompacta o ZIP:

```
public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] compactado) {
    if(compactado == null){
        return "";
    }

    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compactado);

        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
            builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, Charset.defaultCharset()));
        }

        gis.close();
        is.close();

        return builder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Já verificou se o servidor está emitindo os cabeçalhos corretos de codificação de caracteres? Ele precisa informar o browser que o  conteúdo está em UTF8 – pelo seu print, parece que o browser não sabe disso e está tentando exibir como se fosse Latin 1.

Comment: Olá @bfavaretto acredito que o problema não seja esse, porque coloquei um log com o resultado de builder.toString() antes do return no meu metodo que descompacta e o texto ja esta com os caracteres estranhos.

Comment: `Charset.defaultCharset()`. Já tentou `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`? Você parece estar fixando UTF-8,  se o servidor tiver outro *default*, e.g., `CP-1252`, o processo de conversão vai falhar.

Comment: Olá @AnthonyAccioly era exatamente isso, não sei como não tinha pensado nisso antes rsrs, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na seguinte linha:

```
builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

O método `defaultCharset` retorna o *charset* padrão do sistema.
Você está forçando UTF-8 para a leitura dos dados no banco. Se o seu servidor estiver configurado com qualquer outro *charset* padrão (e.g., `CP-1252` no Windows) há uma *mismatch* entre *encodings* e o construtor da *string* pode produzir lixo.

Você pode resolver esse problema fixando [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8):

```
builder.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Uma dica adicional é que para *strings* pequenas e Java 9+ você não precisa fazer todo esse malabarismo com *buffers* intermediários e `StringBuilder`. A classe `InputStream` tem um método [`readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) que faz o que você precisa. Ler e converter todo o *array* de *bytes* de uma vez é mais eficiente pois evita a criação e descarte das *strings* intermediárias.

Eis uma possível implementação para o método `convertToEntityAttribute`:

```
public String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] compactado) {
    if(compactado == null) {
        return "";
    }

    try (GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compactado))) {
        return new String(gis.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Você talvez queira ao menos logar a exceção aqui
        return "";
   }
}
```